# Google Sign in with android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I am doing sign in with Google account I have followed for creating a JSON file. Also I have integrate JSON file with my project.But I am getting exception that account.getDisplayName throws nullPointException.

[image]

Google sign in code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private SignInButton signInButton;
private GoogleApiClient client;
private static final int REQ_CODE = 9001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signInButton = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_signin);

    GoogleSignInOptions options = new 
 GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
            enableAutoManage(this,this).
            addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,options).build();

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_signin:
            signIn();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
    public void signIn(){
    Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(client);
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable 
Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE){
        GoogleSignInResult result = 
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleResult(result);
    }
}

 private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()){
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        String name = account.getDisplayName();
            String email = account.getEmail();
            String image = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
    }
}
}
```

and here is my compiled library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

please guide where I am doing mistake

Comment: Do you get other data from the account object?

Comment: try : GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();                                   
       if(account!=null){ String name = account.getDisplayName();
            String email = account.getEmail();
            String image = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();}

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: Yes my googleSIgninIntent has Extras. I have applied this code but also i am getting nullpoint Exception

Comment: I think the problem is in integration with google api's console. make sure that you registered your project package with Sha keys in developers console and added required api keys and permissions in your manifest

Comment: Try with other google account may be the display name is null from result or check account.getDisplayName()!=null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);

            // G+
            Person person  = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            System.out.println("Display Name: " + person.getDisplayName());
            System.out.println("Gender: " + person.getGender());
            System.out.println("AboutMe: " + person.getAboutMe());
            System.out.println("Birthday: " + person.getBirthday());
            System.out.println("Current Location: " + person.getCurrentLocation());
            System.out.println("Language: " + person.getLanguage());

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have applied this but i am getting
E/TAG: Failed!! Google Result Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}

Answer (score 0):

If you want " UserName, Email Id, Profile URL, Google Id" of google.

You have done mistake with "GoogleSignInOptions". Please Replace my GoogleSignInOptions with your GoogleSignInOptions code to resolve your problem.

Then, **Your Solution is here** -> You should follow below code.

```
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private LinearLayout googleBtn;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
           googleBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.googleBtn);


           GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .build();

           mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()))
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), 0, connectionResult -> {
                    Snackbar.make(googleBtn, "Connection failed..", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Google connection Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                        //Log.e(TAG,"mGoogleApiClient is connected");
                        mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                    }
                })
                .build();
            }

        public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
               case R.id.googleBtn:
                       //stopAutoManage first otherwise throws exception Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0
                         if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
                         }
                loginWithGoogle();
                break;
         }

    public void loginWithGoogle() {
        Log.e(TAG, "is connected? " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }


public void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            // Get account information

            if (acct != null) {
                Name = acct.getDisplayName();
                if (acct.getEmail() != null) {
                    Email = acct.getEmail();
                } else {
                    Email = "";
                }

                SocialUserId = acct.getId();
                Gender = "";

                String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
                String profileURL = Objects.requireNonNull(acct.getPhotoUrl()).toString();

                String status = "Status: \nFullname: " + Name + "\n Email: " + Email + "\nProfile URI: " + profileURL;
                Log.i(TAG, "Google signin " + status);
                Log.i(TAG, "ID Token: " + idToken);
                Log.i(TAG, "ID: " + acct.getId());

                //TODO Temporary "acct.getCompId()" pass "idToken"

                checkIsUserExists();
            }

        } else {
            hideProgressBar();
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed!! Google Result " + result.getStatus());

            int status_code = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
            switch (status_code) {
                case GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED:
                    Snackbar.make(googleBtn, "Google sign in has been cancelled.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case GoogleSignInStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR:
                    Snackbar.make(googleBtn, "Application is unable to connect with internet", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                default:
                    //AppUtils.showSnackBar(LandingActivity.this, btnLogin, GoogleSignInStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(result.getStatus().getStatusCode()), R.integer.snackbar_duration_3sec);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have applied this but i am getting E/TAG: Failed!! Google Result Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to integrate Google Sign In in your Android application

Step 1. Implement library

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

Step 2. Add google login button

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
```

Step 3. Add below code in your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signup = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.signup);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, google_login);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.e("called", "called");
    if (requestCode == google_login) {
        Task task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        // Disaplay data on your screen
        Log.e("email", account.getEmail());
        Log.e("name", account.getDisplayName());
        Log.e("id", account.getId());

    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.e("signInResult", ":failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

You can follow this tutorial for complete implementation :- [Sign In with Google in your Android Application](https://trinitytuts.com/signin-with-google-in-your-android-application/)